# Preserving the order of elements when parsing Microdata in Python

Tags: python, json, rdf, microdata, json-ld

I am facing the following problem:

When I am parsing an HTML document with Microdata markup in Python with rdflib, the ordering of elements is lost (which is a natural consequence of RDF not having an order for multiple elements).

E.g. the value method often returns the element that was the first value in the original markup, but not reliably.

Now, sometimes it will be very handy to preserve the original order. Is there a way to tell rdflib to return an ordered list for multiple values?

Or is there a simple Microdata-to-JSON (or JSON-LD) library for Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a very efficient way: Instead of parsing the Microdata into RDF with rdflib, I used Ed Summer's Microdata library at

https://github.com/edsu/microdata

This preserves the original order and is by far the simplest solution I found.